# How to select columns from list of tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a view in which I am selecting the names of tables from a particular schema. How can I use SELECT so that it display the columns and its values from these tables?

```sql
with tables_names as (
  select table_name 
  from information_schema. "columns" 
  where table_schema = 'xx'
)
select * from tables_names
```

Comment: Maybe you need the column lists of all tables in schema 'xx' properly ordered by table name, column ordinal position? Please elaborate on 'display the columns and values of these tables'

Comment: If you want to return the column names you will have to preject them to the CTE. 

```code
select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns
```

Comment: this query select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns returns only name of columns and I also need all values from those columns.

Comment: Maybe then convert all the data from a schema into a long [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) (entity-attribute-value) list and then query from it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the column names in your query just add

> COLUMN_NAME

```
 with tables_names as (
  select table_name, column_name
  from information_schema. "columns" 
  where table_schema = 'xxx'
)
select * from tables_names
```

Comment: I know, but the case is that I need all values from those columns. In general, I want to find a specific value among all the columns of the tables in a given schema

Answer (score 1):

Well, if your purpose is to list db-table column names:

```
declare @tbl nvarchar(100) = 'person'
select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = @tbl
```

Or more "extended" option:

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'dbo'
```

*"can I use SELECT so that it display the columns and its values from these tables"*. If you need to see table data based on table/column name(s):

```
declare @tbl nvarchar(100) = 'person', @col nvarchar(100) = 'age'
exec('select * from ' + @tbl)
exec('select ' + @col + ' from ' + @tbl)
```

Finally, if you want to find a specific value from all colums and all tables, you have to iterate over them using cursor (probably non-cursor option exists, do not see it yet...)

```
declare @sch nvarchar(100), @tbl nvarchar(100), @col nvarchar(100) 

declare column_iterator cursor for
select table_schema, table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'dbo'

open column_iterator
fetch next from column_iterator into @sch, @tbl, @col
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    exec('select ' + @col + ' from ' + @sch + '.' + @tbl)
    -- here you're able to do whatever needed with column values
    fetch next from column_iterator into @sch, @tbl, @col
end
close column_iterator
deallocate column_iterator
```